# Exclude folder in goto (CTRL + P) in Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I can't find a tick to exclude / ignore a folder when I want to open a file with goto or with CTRL + P shortcut. 
For example in a java project I want to open a file to edit some lines, as you know in a project we have src folders and target with the same compiled files, I want ignore all the files above every target folder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the property makes for me

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": ["target",".git"]
```

Comment: For anyone who wonders: This property goes into the "folders" properties, same level as "path".